# query fails in php file but never in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

```
$query = "SELECT *, ((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS($lat * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon - lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance 
            FROM average_temp 
            HAVING distance<=25 
            ORDER BY distance ASC limit 1";
```

I can run the above query without any problems in phpmyadmin but it fails about 20% of the time if I run it through my php file.

This is the code that deals with the query results:

```
if (!$query){
  die ("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
}
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$var = $row['id'];
```

80% of the time it works great and the other 20 it hangs for 30sec and throws this error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\wamp\w

What I'm doing is taking latitude and longitude values from another table and referencing them with this table. The formula works like a charm on finding locations within a given distance. I have it set at 25 miles and only want the closest match but you could change it to give you the nearest # of locations. I found the query [here](http://zcentric.com/2010/03/11/calculate-distance-in-mysql-with-latitude-and-longitude/).

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: what size is your database? How long does a query run in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0006 sec) via myadmin Both tables have about 7,000 rows with 10 columns each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you're not testing the result of the query but the query string itself. It should be something like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if ($result === false){
    die ("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
}
$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$var = $row['id'];
```

That way you should get proper error reporting from MySQL, I'm guessing a timeout since it hangs for 30 seconds.

Comment: Exactly. Was just about to write the same, beat me to it.

Comment: If you are using mysql*i*_query then you should also use mysql *i*_error()

Comment: Also, in your query, just for debugging purposes, remove the `having distance <= 25` and see if it returns any rows. if so, what are the values?

Comment: Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS( * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 18' at line 1

Comment: @whatdafrak What is the value of `$lat`? That is the root of your problem. I guess it comes from user input? Try casting it to a `(float)` before using it in the query.

Comment: I don't understand this. How is the syntax wrong if it works 80% of the time and all I'm changing are the $lat and $lon variables with different locations?

Comment: @whatdafrak Add `$query` to the error output and post the query that is failing here.

Comment: I am pulling those values from another db. They are stored in that db under float(7,4) and same thing with the db I am querying. Are you saying try $lat = float($lat); ?

Comment: @whatdafrak In fact now I look at it properly I can see exactly what the problem is from the error you posted above. `$lat` was empty. You can see this from `... + COS( * PI() / 180) ...` - that should be `... + COS(<some_value_here> * PI() / 180) ...` and that fact that it is empty means there will be a syntax error since the multiplication expression has no left operand. The problem is with the way you are assigning a value to `$lat`

Comment: @DaveRandom You are right. I commented all code after my original pull from the first table of $lat and $lon and did an echo and getting nothing but undefined variables for my first query to the first table. Think I have a bigger problem than I originally thought.

Comment: @whatdafrak You say `I am pulling those values from another db` - my guess is that that original query is failing for some reason. If you edit the question and show the part of your code where you assign a value to `$lat` and `$lon` we'll happily take a look at it.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I have been looking in the wrong place so tomorrow I will look into the original query and see what's going on. Again thanks for the fast responses.

Comment: I found the problem! I was doing a natural join query (matching on city name) and if there were no matches, the entire query failed. Took out the 'natural join table2' and works great. Now just need to figure out how to gracefully query table1 if the join fails. I know I could do 2 separate queries but trying to minimize amount of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Query may fail if $lat or $lon are empty or undefined.
Check them before sending query.

Comment: Thanks for the response. DaveRandom got it just before you did. I thought it was my formula but it was the $lat and $lon were undefined. Thanks again.